CSS style showing &gt; instead of > in R shiny
I'm trying to add a style in shiny but when I check Chrome it shows up as #input-label + div &gt; div {width: 150px}, &gt; should actually be >. What is causing this?
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$style("#input-label + div > div {width: 150px;}"),
  numericInputIcon("input", "input", 42, icon = "Num")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


The issue is that you pass a character string which gets escaped, i.e. the > is replaced by the HTML entity &gt;. To prevent that you have to wrap in HTML() so that

the tag() function will know not to perform HTML escaping on it. (See ?htmltools::HTML).

This is also mentioned in the docs (see ?tags) according to which ... may include

HTML() strings

library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(HTML("#input-label + div > div {width: 150px;}")),
  numericInputIcon("input", "input", 42, icon = "Num")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6399



this happens because chrome read the line as html
try this:
ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$style(HTML("
        #input + div > div {width: 150px;}
    ")),
    numericInputIcon("input", "Input Label", 42, icon = "Num")
)

